# Copy text from host to Vbox

Tags: centos, virtualbox

How to copy text from windows7-host to linux CentOS7 in virtualbox without using VboxAdditions and shared folders?Is it really possible just using keyboard and mouse?

Comment: does virtualbox on windows have an Edit menu?  have you tried the standard Ctrl-Ins (copy, on Win7) and Shift-Ins (paste, on guest) keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: You suggestion doesn't work for me. I have tried it several times. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK with out installing VboxAdditions  , no you cant unless you have taken remote access(internally) via SSH so you can access via Putty or other SSH tools to access.